# integrating tab bar controller with slide menu in iOS

Tags: ios, sidebar

I've used `SWRevealViewController` from [this site](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/) to create slide menu in my app.On the front news page i want different tabs which will lead to different view controllers.Also those different view controllers must have the `UIBarButton` at the top left side,i.e,the slide menu must be available on all the view controllers.
I am trying this for last two or three days but i am getting the error if i embed `SWRevealViewController` in `TabBarController` and also by connecting the vc's with tab bar controller as different tabs.

Can somebody help me out.

Comment: i have implemented the tab bar along with the slide menu somehow today with the help of swrevealviewcontroller itself.But the main problem being faced by me is that the side bar button is available only on first tab and not the other ones.Please if someone can help me out in this.